# What machine learning algorithms are important for quant interviews?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for this SE board. If not, I can definitely remove it. FWIW, I saw a few other interview-related questions posted on here.

Anyways, I will be interviewing for quantitative researcher and developer positions at hedge funds and prop trading firms this summer.

My understanding is the interview processes will certainly solve (1) Probability (brain-teaser) questions (2) Coding questions (puzzles and/or C++-specific questions).

I'm also under the impression that interviews may also cover machine learning methods and other classical statistical concepts, and I was wondering if someone could give me an idea of what kind of ML methods I should know for interviews?

Linear regression using OLS appears to be the most commonly asked ML method, and I've heard that sometimes gradient boosted learners are tested on as well. What about methods like logistic regression, SVM, neural nets, clustering methods, PCA, random forests, etc...?